# Store and get data based on their ids

Tags: java, arraylist, store

I am trying to store data and get it back based on their ids.The datatypes are.

```
int Q_ID -------> Id of the Question
int Type_Question ----> Which type is the Question
ArrayList<String> Options ----> The options are multiple and are determined at run         based on users selection of the options
```

Now i want to store the data.For example in this way.

```
Q_ID=0
Type_question=1
Options.add("handpump");
Options.add("Well");

Q_ID=1
Type_question=1
Options.add("random");
Options.add("answer");
```

Is there a way i can store them so that when i enter the Q_ID = 0 and Type_Question=1; it returns only hand pump and well and if enter Q_ID = 1 and Type_question=1 it returns only random and answer.
It may be too obvious but i couldn't think of anything.Any ideas?

Comment: Different data structures are good for different things.  For efficient lookup, you want a "Dictionary" data structure.  An excellent candidate in Java is the [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html), for example "HashMap<>".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple, slightly hacky way you could do this without defining your own types would be to store these in a HashMap, with a string combining the Q_ID and the Type_Question as a single concatenated string, like so:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> yourHashMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

ArrayList<String> handPumpWell = new ArrayList<String>();
handPumpWell.add("handpump");
handPumpWell.add("well");
yourHashMap.put("0,1", handPumpWell);

ArrayList<String> randomAnswer = new ArrayList<String>();
randomAnswer.add("random");
randomAnswer.add("answer");
yourHashMap.put("1,1", randomAnswer);
```

And then you could reference the list of options for any given ID/Type combination like so:

```
yourHashMap[Q_ID + "," + Type_Question]
```

Which for `Q_ID = 0` and `Type_Question = 1` would return an `ArrayList` containing `"handpump"` and `"well"`.

You'd have to make the sure Q_ID always preceded the Type_Question, though, because rearranging them wouldn't return the correct results.

Comment: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> It gives this error..Any ideas?

Comment: @zeeshandar Try compiling it now - I had a few things wrong.

Comment: yoursHashMap.put("1,1", randomAnswer); instead of yourHashMap["1,1"] = randomAnswer;
thanks its working now..cheers